# sonarqube error on static Calendar variable

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following variable declared :

```
private static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I am using that variable 'calendar' in a static method like below :

```
myStaticMethod(String reqDate){
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date some_date;
    long seconds = 0;
    int value = 10;
    try {
        some_date = df.parse(reqDate);
        calendar.setTime(some_date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, value);
        Date effValueDate = calendar.getTime();
        seconds = (effValueDate .getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //---Do---something----
    }
}
```

I am getting the following sonar error :

```
Make "calendar" an instance variable.
Not all classes in the standard Java library were written to be thread-safe. 
Using them in a multi-threaded manner is highly likely to cause data problems or exceptions at runtime.    
This rule raises an issue when an instance of Calendar, DateFormat, 
javax.xml.xpath.XPath, or javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory is marked static.
```

This is my solution, but I am not sure if the solution quality is good enough.

```
myStaticMethod(String reqDate) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // the do the next processing
}
```

So how can I fix the error... can I use a local `Calendar` variable in this case instead of class variable or is there any other smart way to address this.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using a local Calendar variable (except that you should really be replacing these legacy classes with those from java.time package). The Calendar object contains date information, so why should it be a static class variable in the first place? After all, your Date variable is local, so why should the Calendar variable be different?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`,  `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. All of those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sonar warning is caused because the `calendar` object could be updated from multiple threads.
Either, as you said you could declare the `calendar` as local to the method.

OR 1) Make a synchronized block in your code. (using local `calendar` is better)

```java
Date effValueDate ;
synchronized(calendar) {
    calendar.setTime(some_date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, value);
    effValueDate = calendar.getTime();
}
```

2. **RECOMMENDED:** Use the new java API classes for date and time (`java.time`).

```java
// or use DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

LocalDateTime date = LocalDate.parse(reqDate, pattern).plusDays(value).atStartOfDay();
Duration duration= Duration.between(date, LocalDateTime.now());
long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
```

[Read more](http://baeldung.com/migrating-to-java-8-date-time-api) about the new API

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using the recommended approach as I find it more meaningful.

Comment: @Som it is better to use the new API whenever required instead of the old `java.util.time.Date` https://www.baeldung.com/migrating-to-java-8-date-time-api

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Since you seem to have accepted Gautham M’s recommendation to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, I thought that as a supplement I would rewrite your method using java.time. I may not need to add that I wholeheartedly agree in the recommendation.

```
public static void myStaticMethod(String reqDate) {
    int value = 10;
    try {
        LocalDate dateThen = LocalDate.parse(reqDate).plusDays(value);
        ZonedDateTime dateTimeThen = dateThen.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(Instant.now(), dateTimeThen);
        System.out.println(seconds);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        //---Do---something----
        System.out.println(dtpe);
    }
}
```

To me it appears not only simpler but also more natural to read than the original code using `Calendar` and the other poorly designed classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1.

I am exploiting the fact that your string format is ISO 8601 format for a date, a format that `LocalDate` parses as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

I tried this call in my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen):

```
    myStaticMethod("2021-06-28");
```

Output was:

> 587995

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)